# Are ConcurrentHashMap's compute, computeIfAbsent and computeIfPresent methods entirely atomic?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, atomic, concurrenthashmap

Is the whole method call atomic or is just the BiFunction execution atomic? Is it blocking for all keys or just for the calls on the same key?

Comment: It's worded so that an implementation could block for access to the same segment, bucket or key. You could just look at the OpenJDK source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following details are for OpenJDK Java 11.

These three methods hold a lock on a `Node` in the map while the method is called and the key / value is updated.  This node will typically be the first node in a the chain or tree of nodes for a hash bucket.  Concurrent attempts to insert, update or delete key/value pairs in the same bucket will be blocked until the lock is released.

(The behavior for other versions of Java could be different.)

---

> Is the whole method call atomic or is just the BiFunction execution atomic?

The whole method call.

> Is it blocking for all keys or just for the calls on the same key?

Somewhere in between; see above.  But if you follow this advice in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)), it should not matter.

> *" Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, **so the computation should be short and simple** ..."*

Comment: I just tested the method on Android (see my own answer), like you said, it does not seem to be always blocking for different keys; In my particular case, I want to create a key-bound locking mechanism backed by a CuncurrentHashMap<AnyKey, ReentrantLockWithCounter>; I wonder what would be faster: using a `compute` (never fails) or simply using a `get` (might fail if the entry is removed before increasing the counter, must retry) [probably an unnoticeable difference, but still...]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this with Kotlin coroutines on Android using the following code

```
val incrementalNum = AtomicInteger(0)
val map = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Unit>()
val lastThreadNum = AtomicInteger(-1)
val collisions = AtomicInteger(0)

for (a in 0..1000) GlobalScope.launch {
    val threadNum = incrementalNum.incrementAndGet()
    map.compute(threadNum) { k, v-> lastThreadNum.set(threadNum); Unit.apply {
        Log.e("SLOW", "this operation will slow things")
        if (lastThreadNum.get() != threadNum) Log.e("COLLISION", "Collision Number: ${collisions.incrementAndGet()}")
    }}
}
```

With map.compute(threadNum) i get a fair number of collisions (about 10-30) every time I run it, while using map.compute(1) I never get any collisions.

This seems to indicate that - at least on Android- the ConcurrentHashMap.compute function is only blocking by key (which is a pretty good behaviour for my use case)

I'll try to test this with other Java implementations, if that's the standard/usual implementation, it should probably be documented better